# load html direct by browser vs load with IIS(Visual studio 2019)

Tags: html, css, browser

I have a CSS file and HTML when I'm loading it directly by any browsers all my CSS load perfect except my background Image, although if I'm loading it by any form of an ISS it works fine. I just want to know why! (my background works if I load an image from the internet but I have an issue if I want to load it from my local computer). Thank you!

```css
.flex-row-1 {
  background: url(/images/black.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row-1">
  <div class="your-box">
    <h2>You:<span id="your-result">0</span></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="dealer-box">
    <h2>Dealer:<span id="dealer-result">0</span></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Server will use the slash `/` as the root of the site then look in images folder. Your computer doesn't know the root. Try removing the slash. Your computer will look in the images folder, if it is in the same folder as your html file.